# How do I solve this PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do I solve the partial differential equaiton

$u_{t} = (u_{x})^{-1}$

subject to the conditions $u(t,x) \geq 0$ and $u(0,0) = $0. Use the separation Ansatz $u(t,x) = f(t)g(x)$.

The inverse in confusing me

Answer (score 2):

You have $u_tu_x=1$ and $u=fg$

$u_t=f'g$ and $u_x=fg'$

$u_tu_x=1\implies ff'gg'=1\implies ff'=K=1/(gg')$

$f=\sqrt{2Kt}$ and $g=\sqrt{2x/K}$

$u=2\sqrt{tx}+C$ Not the general solution, but the overall requirement of $u\leq0$ makes it valid and it can fulfill the initial condition of $u(0,0)=0$. So,

$u=2\sqrt{xt}$

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you went from the third to the fourth line?

Comment: Yes, sorry: $(1/2)(f^2)'=(1/2)(f'f+ff')=ff'=K$ And after integrating: $f^2= 2Kt$

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you

Comment: I don't want to be rude, only I can be mistaken, but why don't you close as answered questions that for all respects seem answered? It affects the way the search utility gives results.